# Tricky Trigonometry Problem

Tags: geometry

I solved this problem by applying the law of sines to get the values for $\omega$ (74.61) and $Z$ (5.65) respectively. But now I'm told there is another combination of $\omega$ and $Z$ that will work. How could we find that?

[image: triangle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$\frac6{\sin\omega}=\frac4{\sin40^\circ}\implies\sin\omega=\frac32\sin40^\circ\implies\omega=\begin{cases}74.62^\circ\\{}\\105.38^\circ\end{cases}$$

Since $\,\sin x=\sin(180^\circ-x)\,$ ...

Comment: Ok so then how do we find the value of z?

Comment: Exactly as before, @jaykirby: once for the first option (which you already did)  and once for the second one.

Comment: how come we get two possible angles?

Comment: @jaykirby: $$\sin\omega=\frac32\sin40^\circ\implies \omega=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac32\sin40^\circ\right)=74.62^\circ\;\;or\;\;105.38^\circ  $$

Comment: Remember @jaykirby: $$ \sin x=a\implies x=\begin{cases}\sin^{-1}a\\180-\sin^{-1}a\end{cases} $$

Answer (score 2):

Hint,
given $sin(\omega)=$a positive number, there are two solutions for $\omega$ in the range 0 to 180 degrees.